# postman - how to generate random number in specific range?

Tags: random, postman

I need to generate random number in specific range for postman.
I wonder if there is possible to generate it and to use it in variable in postman, from what I saw at [postman site](https://learning.getpostman.com/docs/postman/environments_and_globals/variables#dynamic-variables) is:

```
{{$randomint }}
```

will give random number between 1-1000
and I already tried to do something like this:

```
{{$randomint(1,5)}}
```

to get number between 1-5 but postman didn't get this kind of option, so how to specify range for the random in postman?

Comment: Just use the built-in functionality and a little bit of math. Round, divide, multiply

Comment: also did try 
    {{$randomint(math.random()*3}}

Comment: Did either of the solutions answer your question?

Comment: no, neither of them workes

Comment: Do you still need an answer for this?

Comment: yes i need, nothing workd till now

Comment: Could someone please correct the typos in the question? The built-in variable is {{randomInt}} with upper case I and without space. People are using this as a reference for random integers. Cheers

Answer (score 69):

You can just use `Lodash` for this as it's a built-in [module](https://lodash.com/docs/#random):

```
pm.environment.set("random_number", _.random(1, 5))
```

Or just add the number `5` to the `_.random()` function and this will be a number from 0 to 5.

Comment: Is there a way to have that random variable change with each use and not just per request? In a request body, each use of {{random_number}} will be the same.

Comment: @Adrian yes, I detail it in my answer

Comment: If I use this `{{random_number}}` in the request as a value for multiple fields in the payload, all of them get the same value for a given request run. Is there a way to get different values for each usage/instance in a single request run?

Comment: If it doesn't need to be between the ranges above, you could just use `{{$randomInt}}`

Comment: @DannyDainton Thanks, I am aware of that, but I need it to be in a range (1-100). Any way to achieve that?

Answer (score 35):

This worked for me:

In your Pre-request script define your variable with:

```
pm.globals.set('randomNumber', Math.floor(Math.random() * 5));
```

Then in your URL call your variable in the URL like so:

```
{{randomNumber}}
```

Hope this works for you.

Comment: This outputs 0-4 and not 1-5!

Answer (score 29):

A little late.
But none of the above answers worked for me.
I solved it by setting a variable in pre-request tab.

Example:

```
pm.collectionVariables.set ("randomNum", _.random (20,100));
```

Then use the variable name in the body of my request (like any other variable)

```
{
    "number": {{randomNum}}
}
```

Finally, this generates a new number between the desired values in each request

Comment: Thanks. But, in my case, this variable won't show on Postman Auto-Generated Docs. In my json there is no variable shown, like this : `{"age": ,}`. Any solution? Is that normal for pre-request variable?

Comment: Sorry, just figured it out. So, I just need to go to Collection, click "Edit", go to tab "Variables", and then define the "Initial Value". As I created new variable in tab "Pre-request Script", it will create a new variable in collection **without any default value**. Thanks.

Answer (score 6):

Just use the modulo operation:

```
const num = pm.variables.replaceIn('{{$randomInt}}') % 5 + 1;
pm.environment.set("random_number", num);

// test
console.log(pm.variables.get('random_number'));
```