# How to generate random numbers in a range of a phone number format Postman

Tags: javascript, random, automated-tests, postman

I want to generate random numbers in a specific range of numbers. I tried solutions provided in this stackoverflow [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48750493/postman-how-to-generate-random-number-in-specific-range) but none of the solutions are working. I am able to generate only 1 random number instead of a specific range of numbers. Is there any other solutions I can use to generate a random number for a specific range?

I'm looking for a range of 10 numbers with random numbers. I am looking for a phone number format. For example: (651) 651-6516

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You use do this in two different ways - You could write some JS code to create random numbers and format it in the way you need or use a 3rd party data generator to do this for you.

By adding this code to the `Pre-Request Script` you can get the `phone` data from the `randomuser.me` API and store this in an `environment` variable to use in the main request.

```
pm.sendRequest("https://randomuser.me/api/?nat=us&inc=phone", (err, res) => {
    pm.environment.set('phoneNumber', res.json().results[0].phone)
})
```

[image: Postman Random]

To use this in the main request, you can use the `{{phoneNumber}}` syntax to add this to the URL or the request body.

Comment: Edited my post.

Comment: I probably would have started the question with the fact that you need to create a phone number... Quite an important detail.